# AC-DC converter (120-230VAC)

Tags: dc, ac, converter

We are designing a circuit which should be powered directly from mains (230VAC), and have in the previous design used a normal transformer.

But in the next design we would like to use an AC-DC converter, since this could make our design more flexible with possible input of 120VAC to 230VAC 50/60Hz.

The output of the converter is preferred to be 5VDC but could be higher.

I have found the bp5048-15 from ROHM, which would do the job.

www.rohm.com/products/databook/pm/pdf/bp5048-15.pdf

Does anyone have a better or cheaper solution?

EDIT: wall adaptor is not an option, we need to supply the product directly with mains.

Comment: And using an off the shelf power adapter INSIDE the case?

Comment: It all needs to be mounted on one pcb. We have limited space.

Comment: Fine, but it's hard to reach the same livel of integration of [this](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/photo/v0/435189970/For_iphone_ipod_Travel_wall_USB_charger.jpg)

Comment: Lots of companies make small "power bricks" intended to be embedded into other products.  They are usually already safety-certified, which is important if you want to sell this publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Power Integrations TinySwitch can also be used to make a simple non-isolated rail for low-power applications. I've had success with these parts in the past.

http://www.powerint.com/en/products/tinyswitch-family

(apologies for the pasted link, SE sites with iOS Safari are painful to use)

Comment: Thanks, I will go with one of the integrated power switches. Probably one from ROHM, since they meet our demands better.